# The problem of finding the maximum coefficient term in the binomial expansion,Find the value range of K

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The problem is shown in the figure, and the result should be the range of K obtained at the end of the image

[image]

```
Reduce[{Binomial[n, k] a^(n - k) b^k >= 
   Binomial[n, k + 1] a^(n - k - 1) b^(k + 1), 
  Binomial[n, k] a^(n - k) b^k >= 
   Binomial[n, k + 1] a^(n - k + 1) b^(k - 1), n >= k > 0, a > 0, 
  b > 0}, k]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a typo for the last `Binomial`:  It should be `Binomial[n, k-1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eq1 = Binomial[n, k] a^(n - k) b^k >= Binomial[n, k + 1] a^(n - k - 1) b^(k + 1);
eq2 = Binomial[n, k] a^(n - k) b^k >= Binomial[n, k - 1] a^(n - k + 1) b^(k - 1);

eq1a = MultiplySides[eq1, a^(-n + k + 1) b^(-k)/((n - k) Binomial[n, k]), 
   Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && n >= k > 0] // FunctionExpand
```

[image: eq1a]

```
eq2a = MultiplySides[eq2, a^(-n + k) b^(-k + 1)/(k Binomial[n, k]), 
   Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && n >= k > 0] // FunctionExpand
```

[image: eq2a]

```
Reduce[{eq1a, eq2a, a > 0, b > 0, n >= k > 0, n ∈ Integers, k ∈ Integers}, k]
```

[image: Result of reduce]

Comment: What do the two steps (eq1a and eq2a)added in the middle represent? Why do you operate like this? What is the application?

Comment: Multiplying both sides of your equations by appropriate values gives the simplified equations (given in your question and still using `Binomial`) which gets you a solution.

Comment: How did you choose the combination number multiplied by the left and right sides of the equation?

Comment: I don't know how to make it "automatic" so "by inspection" I put in the values that would result in the simplified equations.

Comment: The formula for multiplying the left and right sides only needs to keep the exponents of a and b constant, and after the combination number is reduced, only the formulas for n and k are included

Answer (score 4):

If you use the last relations you show instead of Binomial, then it can solve it

```
ClearAll[a, n, k, b];
Reduce[a/(n - k) > b/(k + 1) && b/k >= a/(n - k + 1) && n >= k > 0 && 
  a > 0 && b > 0, k]
```

[image]

Comment: ```Reduce[{FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k]] a^(n - k) b^k >= 
    FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k + 1]] a^(n - k - 1) b^(k + 1), 
   FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k]] a^(n - k) b^k >= 
    FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k + 1]] a^(n - k + 1) b^(k - 1), 
   n >= k > 0, a > 0, b > 0}, k] // FullSimplify```Is there a way to keep Binomial?

Comment: @csn899  It could not do it with Binomial in there. I am using V 13.2.1. May be there is a trick to do it. Wait and see if someone comes with an idea.